# Testing Laravel Livewire sorting component

Tags: laravel-livewire

I'm trying to test a sort by call for a table, The sort by works in practice but I cannot generate a failing test, my test always passes so I'm not testing it correctly.

Steps to Reproduce:

This is the test:

```
Livewire::test(Roles::class)
        ->call('sortBy', 'blah')
        ->assertSet('sortField', 'blah')
        ->call('roles')
        ->assertStatus(200);
```

the param blah should match a database column, I don't have a column called blah so should fail, but it passes.

the component:

```
class Roles extends Component
{
    use WithPagination;

    public $paginate;
    public $query;
    public $sortField = 'name';
    public $sortAsc = true;

    protected $queryString = ['query'];

    public function render()
    {
        abort_if_cannot('view_roles');

        return view('livewire.roles.roles');
    }

    public function builder()
    {
        return Role::orderBy($this->sortField, $this->sortAsc ? 'asc' : 'desc');
    }

    public function sortBy($field)
    {
        if ($this->sortField === $field) {
            $this->sortAsc = ! $this->sortAsc;
        } else {
            $this->sortAsc = true;
        }

        $this->sortField = $field;
    }

    public function roles()
    {
        $query = $this->builder();

        if ($this->query) {
            $query->where('name', 'like', '%'.$this->query.'%');
        }

        return $query->paginate($this->paginate);
    }

    public function deleteRole($id): void
    {
        abort_if_cannot('delete_roles');

        $this->builder()->findOrFail($id)->delete();

        $this->dispatchBrowserEvent('close-modal');

    }
}
```

Are you using the latest version of Livewire: v2.3.6

If I attempt to run:

`wire:click.prevent="sortBy('blah')`

Then I do get an SQL error as expected.

Anyone know how I can update my test to actually see there's an error.

Comment: I tried to simulate your scenario and I am getting the same results. Failing from frontend, not failing from tests. I tried to xdebug and where prepared database statements throw exception on the frontend - no exception is being thrown from my in memory sqlite test environment. Weird. I haven't found the reason. Just curious - do you also use in memory sqlite for testing? Btw do you seed the roles table in your tests? Because if it's empty, the paginator will return 0 results and the consequent query is not being run at all.

Comment: thanks yes I also use sqlite in memory and I do indeed seed users and roles so I know it's not empty, I have other tests that do fail as expected, it's a strange one.